# Generate structured logs java

Tags: java, logging

I'm new with JAVA.

I want to ask how can I generate logs like this bellow using java.

```
{"log_level":"INFO","timestamp":"2021-12-23T08:39:48.444706Z",
"event_type":"abc_c","capture_id":"400011","cap_pid":"00053716",
"deb":"0100","no_id":"0011",
"msg_id":"d8c5derbn5-63cb-11ec-8980-0242ac110004","module":"S_TH}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want JSON in the log file
(your example is not valid JSON),
you can use [slf4j-json-logger](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.savoirtech.logging/slf4j-json-logger)

Here is a [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-log-json-output) that discusses more JSON logging solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SLF4j and logback, you can use the  ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.JsonLayout from https://github.com/qos-ch/logback-contrib/wiki/JSON.

```
<appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
        </layout>
</appender>
```

Or if your target is Grafana Loki, you can send the logs directly via https://loki4j.github.io/loki-logback-appender/

For log4j2, there's the built-in JsonLayout:

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleJSONAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="false">
       </JsonLayout>
   </Console>
</Appenders>
```

However, this will only include default attributes like timestamp, loglevel, logger name, and message. If you want to add custom attributes, SLF4J has an Mapped Diagnostic Context for that:

```
    MDC.put("transaction.id", tx.getTransactionId());
    MDC.put("transaction.owner", tx.getOwner());
    logger.info("my message");
    MDC.clear();
```

Logback will automatically add all MDC key-values as a JSON map under the "mdc" attribute.

If you're using log4j2, the MDC is called ThreadContext.

```
    ThreadContext.put("myKey", "myValue");
    log.info("Here's a message!");
    ThreadContext.clear();
```

For log4j2, you need to explicitly add the context keys to the JsonLayout.

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleJSONAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <JsonLayout complete="false" compact="false">
            <KeyValuePair key="myKey" />
       </JsonLayout>
   </Console>
</Appenders>value="${ctx:myKey}"/>
```